# How to install TensorFlow packages without error by using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmd, pip

I am installing TensorFlow for the python3.8 version using pip. It is downloading most of the packages, but it is not able to install some packages and it is throwing an error like this :

> Installing collected packages: tensorflow
> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\vssnr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\include\external\com_github_grpc_grpc\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\grpclb\client_load_reporting_filter.h'
> HINT: This error might have occurred since this system does not have Windows Long Path support enabled. You can find information on how to enable this at https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/enable-long-paths

Please inform me how to download the TensorFlow without any mistakes like this. Or how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Open your Windows PowerShell with Admin access and try inputting this :

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

And after, try to run the pip command to install TensorFlow again and you are able to install it